# Image not loading on live site

Tags: css, image, github

Image not loading on live site. On my local computer the code runs fine, here is the link to the live site: https://apin1992.github.io/web-developer-portfolio/
[image]
but when added to GitHub pages the live site isn't loading the banner image for the header
[image]
here is the CSS on my local computer via VS Code
[image]
and here is the CSS on my GitHub repo
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to change the path to "./images/..." or "../images/..." but with no success. I changed the image path with another in the images folder with no succes. Im not sure what I am doing wrong. Please Help.

Comment: Please inspect your browser's network console. I would assume that loading the image throws a 404 error? Keep in mind that `/images` is an absolute path

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect your github website in the browser, the console gives you the information that the **image can't be found (404)** as well as a model-1.jpg.

By referencing the local path in your CSS the real path on github is: https://apin1992.github.io/images/banner-2.png which is not available.

Did you upload the image to github somewhere? if so, you'll need this reference then.

You can't reference a local image on your PC and expect github to magically have it available. The image must be somewhere online (github or somewhere else) and then in your CSS you need to reference the image with the full https://... address.

##### Explanation of ./ and ../

./ references the root of the project. ../ goes one folder up

if you have a structure of (very basic here)

```
root/ 
    index.html

    images/
        page/
            background.png
            image.png
        header/
            header.png
    css/
        styles.css
```

in styles.css:

./image.png will be root/image.png → 404 not found

../image.png will be one folder up from css/ → root/image.png → 404 not found

You would need ../images/ or ./images/ then page/image.png → one folder up to root or start in root / into images / into page / actual image

---

<sub>If this answer solves your issue, please mark it as correct answer.</sub>